# integer to string conversion in D

Tags: casting, d, phobos

How in D would I cast integer to string?
Something like

```
int i = 15
string message = "Value of 'i' is " ~ toString(i); // cast(string) i - also does not work
```

Google brought me the answer on how to do it with tango, but I want the phobos version.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
import std.conv;

int i = 15;
string message = "Value of 'i' is " ~ to!string(i);
```

or `format`:

```
import std.string;
string message = format("Value of 'i' is %s.", i);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `to` from std.conv:

```
int i = 15
string message = "Value of 'i' is " ~ to!string(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import std.conv;
auto i = 15;
auto message = text("Value of 'i' is ", i);
```

there are also wtext an dtext variants witch returns wstring and dstring.